# What is this Error? + LibGDX + super jumper

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

i just play around with superJumper, and i change something on that. after updating to SDK 17 i get some problems. but i solve them. now i can run my android project. but when i touch any of my settings (like start game or settings or on\off sound) i get Error. it's my LogCat. i can't understand what is this error for. if someone know , plz help me. thanks.

```
04-18 19:26:36.884: D/dalvikvm(9455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 49% free 3008K/5895K, external                      90K/513K, paused 2ms+6ms
04-18 19:26:44.791: I/dalvikvm(9455): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
04-18 19:26:44.791: I/dalvikvm(9455): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
04-18 19:26:46.693: I/dalvikvm(9455): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
04-18 19:26:50.077: W/dalvikvm(9455): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401f6560)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound.play
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.Jumper.Assets.playSound(Assets.java:115)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.Jumper.MainMenuScreen.update(MainMenuScreen.java:39)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.Jumper.Game.render(Game.java:34)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:423)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1364)
04-18 19:26:50.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1119)
04-18 19:27:58.353: I/Process(9455): Sending signal. PID: 9455 SIG: 9
```

[LogCat](http://alkaos.com/images/271LogCat2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound.play` means that you're trying to run that method `play()` but it's not a real method as you're using it. In this case, that's because [`com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound`](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.java) is an interface, not a full class.

The comments in that source file say to use `Audio.newSound(FileHandle)` to create an actual `Sound` object. This probably means calling something like this:

```
FileHandle handle = new FileHandle("path/to/sound.mp3");
Sound mySound = Gdx.audio.newSound(handle);
```

I'm just going based on the source code, so I may be missing something, but I think that should do it. This [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ra3H5UHLRGU) might also help.

Comment: thanks for your reply.for now i can't check your link, but i do something. i just replace my libraries to new one. i mean libgdx-0.9.3 and its work. but thanks for your link again. i can now watch this movies and learn more about libgdx.